# как вызвать метод в функции конструктора new

Tags: javascript

как можно вызвать метод caller в функции actions?

```
"use strict";

let NewsWidget = new function() {
    let root = this;
    this.init = function () {
        this.actions();
    },
    this.actions = function () {
        let elems = document.querySelectorAll(".elem");
        for (let i = 0; elems.length > i; i++) {
            elems[i].onclick = function () {
                this.classList.toggle("active");

                root.caller(5, 2);
            }
        }
    },
    this.caller = function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }
};
NewsWidget.init();
```

Comment: `this.actions = function () { this.caller(1,2); ...`  Замените запятые после определения функций на точки с запятыми.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let NewsWidget = new function() {
    let root = this;
    this.init = function () {
        this.actions();
    },
    this.actions = function () {
        let elems = document.querySelectorAll(".elem");
        for (let i = 0; elems.length > i; i++) {
            elems[i].onclick = function () {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                console.log(root.caller(5, 2));
            }
        }
    },
    this.caller = function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }
};
NewsWidget.init();
```

```html
<div class="elem">ASDFGHJKL</div>
```